# How to use angular factory, $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building my first app with angular and currently I have my service defined as

```
angular.module('mean.testruns').factory('Testruns', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('testruns/:testrunId', {
        testrunId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);
```

I have added another url on the rest server as

```
'/testcases/:testcaseId/testruns'
```

How do I include this in the above testruns factory function?

I currently have my controller as

```
$scope.findOfTestcase = function() {
    //Need to correct this
    Testruns.query({testcaseId:$stateParams.testcaseId}, function(testruns) {
        $scope.testruns = testruns;
    });
};

$scope.findOne = function() {
    Testruns.get({
        testrunId: $stateParams.testrunId
    }, function(testrun) {
        $scope.testrun = testrun;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not totally sure about this, but you could try something like:

```
angular.module('mean.test').factory('Testruns', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    return {
        runs: $resource('testruns/:testrunId', ...),
        cases: $resource('testcases/:testcaseId', ...)
    }
}]);
```

And use it like this:

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'Testruns', 
    function($scope, Testruns) {
        $scope.testCases = Testruns.cases.query();
    }
])
```

Comment: -1 `Testruns` factory is what should be injected into the controller. Also - `mean.test` module doesn't have a `Test` provider shown.

Comment: My bad, I picked the wrong name. A downwote seems a little too extreme anyway. I corrected the code.

Comment: You set the injected name of the factory to that of the module, then referenced a provider not in the module, which would have thrown an error. I gave you feedback. I removed the -1 and gave you points.

Comment: I got confused with the names while trying to keep them as in the OP's example, sorry. Don't worry anyway, you did right :)